# Make it clear in the tour that Super User may be an alternative place to ask

Tags: discussion, tour

I asked a question two days ago. I did assume I was scratching the edges of the site’s scope, but I didn’t know at the time it was actually outside scope. I do realise that now and I also understand the accompanying downvote I got. No offences in the way my question was handled.

However, I was rather baffled by the close reason suggesting I go to Super User. As a Stack Exchange user typically staying confined in the sites they are active in and not paying much attention to hot network questions, all I knew about Super User is what is written in the list of sites:

> For computer enthusiasts and power users.

Nothing in that suggests that I could ask any question related to hardware there and maybe have it be on-topic. It sounds much more like a using-software site. It’s not until I actually open Super User’s tour to find there:

> Ask about … Specific issues with computer software, **hardware** or networking [bolding by me]

There is also [this recent meta-question](https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/552/4326) which basically asks why hardware support is off-topic here with an answer stating that some hardware support may be on-topic.

**In my opinion, this information should be easier to find for new users to this site** (who are already familiar with Stack Exchange in general but not an expert on different sites’ scopes).

---

I therefore suggest adding a note somewhere along this Stack Exchange’s tour that questions about existing hardware may be on-topic at Super User to prevent others running into this issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I thought we'd already done this, but apparently we hadn't.

I've added a note that Super User may be suitable both at the top of the [help center](/help) and under the "don't ask about..." section of the [tour](/tour).